# Pointer being treated as an unmodifiable lvalue in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2013, lvalue, unmodifiable

getNode():

```
    Node<type> getNode(int position) {
        Node<type> *item = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < position; ++i) {
            item = item->next;
        }
        return *item;
    };
```

Node Swapping Code:

```
        Node<Guitar*> temp;
        temp.element = list.getNode(l).element;
        temp.next = list.getNode(l).next;
        list.getNode(l).element = list.getNode(h).element;
        list.getNode(l).next = list.getNode(h).next;
        list.getNode(h).element = temp.element;
        list.getNode(h).next = temp.next;
```

I am working on a project for my computer science class and it is due in a couple of days. I want to sort a linked list using quicksort which is fairly simple, but I have been struggling with a strange issue while swapping nodes in the list. For reference, the getNode() function returns a node at a certain index in the list and the nodes hold a pointer to a guitar object along with the a next node pointer. I have been experimenting for hours now and I figured out that the line such as this, "list.getNode(h).element = temp.element;" is saying that the pointer to a guitar object in a node in the list is being assigned the value of the pointer in the temp object. This would normally work but I get an error at this point saying that the left side is not a modifiable lvalue. However I could make a pointer and put it on the left side of the assignment operator without any errors. Also, the left hand side has no error when I use the dereferencing operator (*) in front, but this does not successfully swap the nodes. I must be missing something.

Comment: Show us the declaration of `getNode`, at least.

Answer (score 2):

The return type of your function should be a reference type--otherwise you're telling the compiler to copy construct an object from the value you're returning, and use that as the return value.

I've written an example, which can be found [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e507c994814e575e). It constructs a vector to pass in to the getting function for simplicity's sake, which returns a dereferenced pointer to one of the component objects. If you examine the output of the program, it will merrily inform you that it is copy constructing the value, not getting a reference to it--any changes you make to a node 'retrieved' from the `getNode` function will be made to a node copy-constructed from the node you want.

I suspect this is also why you're getting an issue with non-modifiable lvalues, since you're attempting to assign values to temporary variables.

tl;dr:
Your `getNode` function is returning a temporary object. Make it return a reference, instead.

Comment: I agree with your answer, it was a while ago that I had to learn that same struggle, when I was new to and learning c++! The good thing is once you understand what is happening behind the scenes and know what to look for it eventually gets easier to work with. The only thing I struggle with in c++ anymore is when templates become complex when multiple inheritance & specialization comes into play. I'm not doing to bad for being self taught :)